# PDE Change of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This ballistic deposition [paper](https://www.lptmc.jussieu.fr/user/viot/ARTICLES/18.pdf) (Viot et al., 1993) contains the following (starting on the second page of the document):

> Introducing the function $H_a(t)$ such that $G(h,t) = \exp[-(h-1+2a)t]H_a(t)$ for $h \geq 1$ and using Eq. (1), one gets the differential equation $$\frac{d \ln{H_a(t)}}{d t} = 2e^{-t} \Big[a + \frac{1}{t} \Big]$$

Now, starting from Eq.1, I attempt to replicate this:

$$\frac{\partial G(h, t)}{\partial t} = -(h-1+2a)G(h,t) + 2aG(h+1,t) + 2\int_{h+1}^\infty G(h',t) dh'$$

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \Big[\exp[-(h-1+2a)t]H_a(t) \Big] = -(h-1+2a)\exp[-(h-1+2a)t]H_a(t) + 2a\exp[-(h+2a)t]H_a(t) + 2\int_{h+1}^\infty \exp[-(h'-1+2a)t]H_a(t) dh'
$$

$$ \frac{d H_a(t)}{d t} \exp[-(h-1+2a)t] = 2a\exp[-(h+2a)t]H_a(t) + \frac{2H_a(t)\exp[-(2a+h)t]}{t} 
$$

$$ \frac{d H_a(t)}{d t} \exp[-(h-1+2a)t] = 2a\exp[-(h+2a)t]H_a(t) + \frac{2H_a(t)\exp[-(2a+h)t]}{t} 
$$

$$ \frac{d H_a(t)}{d t} = 2H_a(t)e^{-t} \Big[ a + \frac{1}{t} \Big] $$

Which is clearly very close to the quoted result, but not exactly. Dividing both sides by $H_a(t)$ doesn't get me there, so I must be missing something!

Comment: Why the downvotes without a reason given? Not exactly helpful

Answer (score 1):

The only thing in which you are wrong is in saying that dividing both sides by $H_a(t)$ wouldn't get you there. Dividing both sides by $H_a(t)$ is exactly the last step. The catch though, is that you need to remember the table derivative for the logarythm:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}ln(u(t)) =  \frac{1}{u(t)}u'(t) $$

(for $u(t) \gt 0$)

You then have:

$$ \frac{1}{H_a(t)}\frac{dH_a(t)}{dt} = 2e^{-t}\left[a + \frac{1}{t}\right] $$
$$ \frac{d[ln(H_a(t))]}{dt} = 2e^{-t}\left[a + \frac{1}{t}\right] $$

Good luck in your studies

Comment: Of course, apologies I was thinking that dividing both sides by $H_a(t)$ would give me $\frac{d 1}{dt}$ on the left hand side, which is of course not the case. Thanks!